# Sharing styles between several GridView controls

Tags: xaml, gridview, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I need to style several `GridView` throughout my application with the same visual styles. This style includes customizing the `ItemsPanel` property as well as the `GroupStyle` property.

My problem is that the `GroupStyle` property of `GridView` is not a dependency property. So the code I would have liked to write (see below) does not work.

Do you know a clean way to share a style (including `GroupStyle`) between several `GridView`s?

The only thing I can think of is using a `GroupStyleSelector` but it's kind of stupid since there is no selection to make: it's always the same `GroupStyle` that's being used. Moreover, I suspect it wouldn't be reflected at design time in VS & Blend.

The code I would love to use:

```
<GridView 
     ItemsSource="..."
     ItemTemplate="..."
     Style="{StaticResource MainMenuStyle}"/>

<Style TargetType="GridView" x:Key="MainMenuStyle">
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            ...
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="GroupStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <GroupStyle>
                ...
            </GroupStyle>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Can you just make your grid layout the way you want it as a `UserControl` and expose the dependency properties for things like your 'ItemsSource' so you can apply it to the instance allowing you to recycle the same template but still populate the different data?

Comment: Yeah, looks like the way to go looking at answers. Didn't learn yet about `UserControl`, seems like a good time to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've a solution and that will definitely work as per your question, but though you should decide whether to use that in your case or not.

> - If you have to make same style of a control in all over the project,    then you should make one common folder and in that folder
>     create one    "Custom User Control" and apply all of your style and
>     customize it    however you want.
> - After that when you need to apply that same kind of style on same       control (any grid control) then simply add that customized user
>     control instead of predefined control

**By doing this you'll also achieve MVC architecture and modularity.**

I'm developing Windows 8 Metro app in C# with XAML, and in that whenever i wanted this approach then i always use this solution and it always works...

to create custom user control, you should use **visual studio** & in that **right click on project -> add -> new item -> User Control**

(Sorry if you couldn't find your solution here, but i think this might help...)

Comment: Thanks, looks like the same lead as the other answer. I'll give it a shot asap.

Answer (score 2):

I've got a magical happy solution.

You can create a custom Attached Property that you set in the Style, and upon setting it internally sets the GroupStyle property on the GridView.

Attached Property:

```cs
// Workaround for lack of generics in XAML
public class GroupStyleCollection : Collection<GroupStyle>
{
}

public class GroupStyleHelper
{
    public static ICollection<GroupStyle> GetGroupStyle(ItemsControl obj)
    {
        return (ICollection<GroupStyle>)obj.GetValue(GroupStyleProperty);
    }

    public static void SetGroupStyle(ItemsControl obj, ICollection<GroupStyle> value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(GroupStyleProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty GroupStyleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "GroupStyle",
            typeof(ICollection<GroupStyle>),
            typeof(GroupStyleHelper),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, OnGroupStyleChanged));

    private static void OnGroupStyleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ItemsControl itemsControl = d as ItemsControl;
        if (itemsControl == null)
            return;

        RefreshGroupStyle(itemsControl, GetGroupStyle(itemsControl));
    }

    private static void RefreshGroupStyle(ItemsControl itemsControl, IEnumerable<GroupStyle> groupStyle)
    {
        itemsControl.GroupStyle.Clear();

        if (groupStyle == null)
            return;

        foreach (var item in groupStyle)
        {
            itemsControl.GroupStyle.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

XAML Style:

```xml
    <Style TargetType="ItemsControl">
        <Setter Property="GroupStyleTest:GroupStyleHelper.GroupStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <GroupStyleTest:GroupStyleCollection>
                    <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="15" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Foreground="HotPink"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </GroupStyleTest:GroupStyleCollection>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Disclaimer: I'm testing this in WPF rather than WinRT but it should work the same, as far as I can tell. That's also why I'm using an ItemsControl rather than GridView, but the property is ItemsControl.GroupStyle anyway.